# Any good source for gem "versioned"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am looking for a source from where I can read about gem/plugin called versioned. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these sources for documentation?

- https://github.com/twoism/versioned
- http://rubydoc.info/gems/versioned/0.2.1/frames
- https://rubygems.org/gems/versioned

Comment: can you help me one more thing. My prob is , I am changing a status of user on checking check_box (for eg; status 2 to 1) , now when I want to go back to status when I uncheck check box (which is 1 to 2). I can use latest_version value and can do it but problem is user might update for many reason but i am looking specifically for when i check/uncheck check_box. Am i making sense?

Comment: I think so. I would recommend you create another attribute user_checked_box? that would track when a user has actually checked the check box.  That way you can track if a user has gone from version 1 to 2 or back depending on if the attribute is populated.

Comment: Here What I want....I am using version gem n User, user.version gives me version 3. Now I will do user.changes_between(2,3) which give me {"status"=>["Yes", "No"]}. (and this yes/no depends on check box). Now I want to move back on status "Yes". How I will read this yes/no from status and flip the status???

Comment: I actually don't have any familiarity with this gem.  I would recommend taking a look at the source code and documentation or posting in StackOverflow with your question.

Comment: i dont have source code. all I want to do if status == "no" then  go back to status yes, or whatever, everytime i want if status is no then go back to which is first in array "status"=>["Yes", "No"]}. Problem is I dont no how to compare staus == "no"??